# How to plot supertorus or toroid surface in VTKi

Tags: python, vtk

I started using **vtki** (https://pypi.org/project/vtki) a helper module for the Visualization Toolkit (VTK) using python. It is quite easy to visualize 3D surfaces which I am using for rapid prototyping however it has some limitations as compared to VTK.

One problem, I have, is to visualize supertoroid surfaces which I could do with VTK using `vtk.vtkParametricSuperToroid()` class but I cannot find similar functionality in vtki. vtki provides only simple surfaces.

I was wondering if someone has some experience how to plot supertoroid surfaces with vtki. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `vtkParametricSuperToroid` class is not wrapped within PyVista, I found another solution and used `vista.StructuredGrid` class to define supertoroidal surfaces. I created a function **supertorus** and used it to plot supertoroidal surfaces with PyVista's `vista.add_mesh()`.

```
import vista
import numpy as np

def supertorus(yScale, xScale, Height, InternalRadius, Vertical, Horizontal):
    #  initial range for values used in parametric equation
    n = 100
    u = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, n)
    t = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, n)
    u, t = np.meshgrid(u, t)

    # a1: Y Scale <0, 2>
    a1 = yScale
    # a2: X Scale <0, 2>
    a2 = xScale
    # a3: Height <0, 5>
    a3 = Height
    # a4: Internal radius <0, 5>
    a4 = InternalRadius
    # e1: Vertical squareness <0.25, 1>
    e1 = Vertical
    # e2: Horizontal squareness <0.25, 1>
    e2 = Horizontal

    # Definition of parametric equation for supertorus
    x = a1 * (a4 + np.sign(np.cos(u)) * np.abs(np.cos(u)) ** e1) *\
        np.sign(np.cos(t)) * np.abs(np.cos(t)) ** e2
    y = a2 * (a4 + np.sign(np.cos(u)) * np.abs(np.cos(u)) ** e1) *\
        np.sign(np.sin(t)) * np.abs(np.sin(t)) ** e2
    z = a3 * np.sign(np.sin(u)) * np.abs(np.sin(u)) ** e1

    grid = vista.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
    return grid
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of PyVista (formerly vtki - we had to change the name recently): https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista and I'm so happy to see you've been enjoying this software!

At this time, the `vtk.vtkParametricSuperToroid` class is currently not wrapped in PyVista - I have created a feature request here: https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues/213

Please feel free to chime in there and give us some example code on how to create and use a `vtk.vtkParametricSuperToroid` object.

We have several requests to wrap all the VTK classes and this would easily fit into those efforts, we just need some help in understanding all thee other atypical mesh types.